# width of floated div pushed down

Tags: html, css

I have floated two divs **left** but the div on the right has a huge text(without br s) and it is pushed down

what should i do in the css such that to make sure the right div does not push down

I had tried giving it a width but width does not take the rest of the screen as different computers have different screen sizes...

http://jsfiddle.net/4ZGmj/

thanks

Pradyut

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you have to set `width` for at least one element. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZGmj/6/

Comment: I had tried giving it a width but width does not take the rest of the screen as different computers have different screen sizes...

Comment: you could use `table-cell` property but this, but will not work for ie7 and below. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4ZGmj/13/

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the second div a width. Otherwise it will just take whatever room it can get (because of the large text without br's).
And when it gets too wide it won't float anymore.
So if you add something like `width:400px;` it will float like you want it to.

Comment: Anything without width such that it takes rest of the width.

Comment: If you want to do it without widths, I'm afraid that you will have use tables. Or you could set `max-width` if you want to leave it dynamic but also want it to work :).

Comment: But remember tables are for tabular data only, not layout :)

Comment: I would like to add that this isn't really user friendly. I have 1680px wide screen but I would hate it if a website was actually 1680px wide..

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are trying to create a 2 Column Fluid Layout. Might I suggest the following example?

http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/layouts/item/css-liquid-layout-21-fixed-fluid/

Answer (score 1):

I have updated your fiddle again, this time the left column is a static width and the right is fluid. CSS is as follows:

```
.ldiv {
    float: left;
    clear:none;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:red;
    width:200px;

}
.mid_div {
    padding: 10px;
    float:none;
    clear:none;
    margin:0 0 0 220px;
    width:auto;
}
```

You might want to test this in IE though.

Regards,
Simon

Comment: can you press the save button on jsfiddle and you will get a new url.. just paste it here...i have tried out your code btw.... thanks...

Comment: Bear in mind that because the right div has no float, I set it's margin to be the width of the left div, PLUS 20px of breathing room, you can play with this of course...

Answer (score 0):

I have updated your fiddle for you. You need to explicitly set a width for both divs, because with your large body of text the div will scale to as wide as it needs to be.

Updated CSS looks like follows:

```
.ldiv {
    float: left;
    clear:none;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:red;
    width:300px;
    margin:0 20px 0 0;

}

.mid_div {
    padding: 10px;
    float:left;
    clear:none;
    width:300px;

}
```

You'll notice that clear:none; has been added to both divs, this means the div will not be pushed to the next line.

Regards,
Simon

Comment: i wanted something without width such that it is the same for small and wide screens...